# 'inet_ntop' was not decleared in this scope

Tags: c++, windows, tcp

```cpp
if (getnameinfo((sockaddr *) & client, sizeof(client), host, NI_MAXHOST, service, NI_MAXSERV, 0) == 0)
{
    std::cout << host << " Connected on port " << service << std::endl;
}
else
{ 
    inet_ntop(AF_INET, &client.sin_addr, host, NI_MAXHOST);
    std::cout << host << " Connected on port " << ntohs(client.sin_port) << std::endl;
}
```

I hoped to get "host" connected on port, but instead I get the error:

> 'inet_ntop' was not declared in this scope

I have tried to add more `#include` statements, which didn't work. I think I get the error because I maybe have an outdated something?

**EDIT**: I need to do a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), but my English is very bad, so it would take me a year to learn/read, so I'm gonna find help another place :-)

Comment: Was [`ws2tcpip.h`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ws2tcpip/nf-ws2tcpip-inet_ntop) among the include files you tried ?

Comment: This is the "include" files i have ```#include <w32api.h>
#include <SdkDdkver.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>


#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
``` @WhozCraig

Comment: Pro tip: did you know that if you google "<function name> windows", you are very likely to get an immediate link to Microsoft's official documentation of the library function, as the first hit, that contains everything you need to know including which header files you need to include?

Comment: Well i did and the thing it says is ws2tcpip.h which i had from the start @SamVarshavchik

Comment: In that case, your next step would be to [edit] your question and show a [mre], which means that everyone else can cut/paste ***exactly what's shown in your question*** , then compile and reproduce your error (which is not the case right now). See "[ask] questions" in Stackoverflow's [help].

Comment: It says "…Minimal – Use as little code as possible that still produces the same problem" which i already did? So to get you right do i need to copy and paste all of my code?

Comment: I can't copy/paste/compile what you've shown to duplicate the error. It is not complete. Add your headers and put that code in a `main` function, hardcode some values for client, host, and service and you're pretty much done right?

Comment: So i need to add all of the code to the question?!

Comment: @FlicZyV2 No you need to create a [mcve] which we can also try to compile.  With this question it should be about 5 lines of code.  It also should be self-contained ie headers and any types.

Comment: You seem to be using IPv4 protocol. Try ```inet_addr``` and ```inet_ntoa``` instead

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `#include <ws2tcpip.h>` in your code.

But also note that `inet_ntop()` was added to WinSock in Windows Vista, so make sure that your project is configured to target Vista or later, as `ws2tcpip.h` declares `inet_ntop()` only if `NTDDI_VERSION >= NTDDI_VISTA` (0x06000000) (see [Using the Windows Headers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/using-the-windows-headers) and [Update WINVER and _WIN32_WINNT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/modifying-winver-and-win32-winnt)).

If targeting Vista+ at the project/compiler level is not an option (ie, you need to target XP, too), then you can instead import `inet_ntop()` via `GetProcAddress()` at runtime.